# Implementing the mongodb and java connector

Tags: mysql, spring, hibernate, mongodb, hibernate-mapping

i need a connector where the mongodb data should be  accessed in java ..Here the problem is the connector should support hibernate or spring.
If it is an opensource it will be more helpful..
Are there any new mongodb connectors which supports the hibernate.

Answer (score 0):

Try this open source which is jpa based and supports seven datastores in additon to mongodb

https://github.com/impetus-opensource/Kundera/wiki

http://recipes4geeks.com/2011/05/02/working-with-mongodb-using-kundera/

https://github.com/impetus-opensource/Kundera/wiki/Getting-Started-in-5-minutes